# Assembly referencing in azure-functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

```
#r "System.Data"
#r "System.Threading"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement;




public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

// parse query parameter
string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
    .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
    .Value;

if (name == null)
{
    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    name = data?.name;
}

return name == null
    ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
    : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
```

}

I am trying to use an Httptriggered azure function to run DataMovement between cloud blob containers. However I keep getting the following error:

2018-02-06T23:59:58.392 run.csx(12,38): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DataMovement' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2018-02-06T23:59:58.407 Exception while executing function: Functions. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Script compilation failed.
2018-02-06T23:59:58.407 Function completed (Failure, Id=72ab129f-706e-497c-ac70-fcebdd3b41ec, Duration=131ms)

Can I use more assemblys than the list provided here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies

or not? IF so, how?

Comment: Consider switching to precompiled functions instead of `csx` scripts. Referencing libraries and NuGet packages is much more straightforward there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The type or namespace name 'DataMovement' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage'

According to your error, we know the DataMovement reference is not in  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage package.

It belongs to ‘**Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement**’  package.
You could refer to my method to install it in Azure function in azure portal.

Click Azure function>View file>add a new file named 'project.json'(if it does not exist).Write the following code in this file then click run to install package:

```html
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement": "0.7.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Then we could use the 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement' reference:
[image]

> Can I use more assemblys than the list provided here

Yes, you could add assemblys in project.json file and run it to install.